# What does "Nil location provided. Can't build URI." mean when executing AJAX request in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, error-handling, response

I have js file:

```
$('#some_btn').click(function() {    

    var valuesToSubmit = $('#some_form').serialize();
    var url = $('#some_form').attr('action');

    console.log("VALUE: " + valuesToSubmit);
    console.log("URL: " + search_url);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url, //sumbits it to the given url of the form
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {

            console.log("saved");
            console.log(data);

        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Controller action which responses:

```
def some_action()

  ...

  @response = {resp: "ack"}

  respond_with @response do |format|
    format.json { render :layout => false, :text => @response }
  end

end
```

Route:

```
post '/abc/some_action', to: 'abc#some_action'
```

But after executing it I receive:

```
ArgumentError
Nil location provided. Can't build URI.


@response = {resp: "ack"}

respond_with @response do |format| # <--- Error here
  format.json { render :layout => false, :text => @response }
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`respond_with` expects an AR object from which a route could be deduced.

Change with:

```
@response = {resp: "ack"}

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @response }
  format.js   { render json: @response }
end
```

an alternative is to force the controller to render only json for a particular action. Weird because it means you were unable to send the proper request.

But in this case:

```
respond_to :json, :only => :some_action
```

In your action:

```
render json: @response
```

Comment: but then I get a new page, not AJAX. I mean it renders a new page with "{resp: "ack"}" text

Comment: doesn't work - I get a new page with json, not a json handled on the same page

Comment: I have `respond_to :html, :json` at the top in the controller

Comment: now I get `ActionController::UnknownFormat` and still error in the `respond_to do |format|` line

Comment: yeah so you're hitting the raw url without specifying json or anything

Comment: btw, it should enter format.js if it's a real ajax request, didn't it?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get it

Comment: but my guess is you're not triggering an ajax request

Comment: hm, and "submit" instead? checking now

Comment: button, default "submit" type was causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add this line

```
class YourController < ...
respond_to :json
```

and then

```
@response = {resp: "ack"}
respond_with(@response)
```

Comment: I have it - doesn't work: I still get a page reloaded and only json data rendered as text

Comment: Should'nt datatype be 'json' instead of 'JSON'?